# .htaccess redirect 301 let ? after url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

i have problem with my .htaccess file. I have some old URLs i want to redirect with 301. But it makes me one problem.

Old URL:

```
www.domain.com/page/1/uvod/en/
```

New URL:

```
www.domain.com/en/
```

This is my redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /page/1/uvod/en/ http://www.domena.sk/en/
```

But when i insert old URL into browser it show me this:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/?id=1&name=uvod&lang=en
```

Comment: Maybe you have cached an old redirect? Try another browser ;-)

Comment: Please post your entire htaccess file. I bet there are some `RewriteRule`'s there.